# Plot pie chart cleared after populating observableArray with data from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js, flot

I am using knockout.js 2.1 and jquery.flot 0.7. Issue I have is very odd and I couldn't reproduce it on jsfiddle. However, I will try to explain it (hopefully that will be enough).

So I have container to which I am applying my ko view model bindings. Inside that view model I have `ko.observableArray` which populated with data from server using '$.ajax' . Also within tat container I have pie chart (which works fine if I am not making ajax call or just not populating that `ko.observableArray` with data).

Pie chart:

```
<div id="asdasdasd111" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        var dasdasdasdadsasdata = [
            { label: "Series1", data: 10 },
            { label: "Series2", data: 30 },
            { label: "Series3", data: 90 }
        ];

        $.plot('#asdasdasd111', dasdasdasdadsasdata, {
            series: {
                pie: {
                    show: true
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I created function (which passed to ajax's `success`) which ideally demonstrates that problem (CoffeeScript, see compiled javascript below):

```
    callback = (data1) =>
        alert("chart exists")

        @sections.push(new MyNamespace.MySection({ DisplayName: data1[0] })) 
        @sections.push(new MyNamespace.MySection({ DisplayName: data1[1] }))                 
        alert("chart still exists")

        for test in ["asdasd", "qweqwe"]
            @sections.push(new MyNamespace.MySection({ DisplayName: test }))                
        alert("chart still exists")

        for item in data1
            @sections.push(new MyNamespace.MySection(item))                              
        alert("click Ok to make pie chart disappear =[")
```

So problem is when I am using that callback in `$.ajax` `success` that pie chart gets cleared:

```
    $.ajax(
        url: "/api/tools/configurationsections"
        success: callback
    )
```

But everything is fine when I am use it like so:

```
    callback([1, 4, 5, 8])

    setTimeout( ( => callback([1, 4, 5, 8]) ), 3000 )
```

Also I found that everything is fine with ajax call when I am not iterating through data from server - so everything works fine if remove last `for` from `callback`

Please point me what could cause that odd issue as I am already out of any ideas.

**Compiled Javascript:**

```
callback = (function(_this) {
          return function(data1) {
            var item, test, _i, _j, _len, _len1, _ref;
            alert("chart exists");
            _this.sections.push(new MyNamespace.MySection({
              DisplayName: data1[0]
            }));
            _this.sections.push(new MyNamespace.MySection({
              DisplayName: data1[1]
            }));
            alert("chart still exists");
            _ref = ["asdasd", "qweqwe"];
            for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
              test = _ref[_i];
              _this.sections.push(new MyNamespace.MySection({
                DisplayName: test
              }));
            }
            alert("chart still exists");
            for (_j = 0, _len1 = data1.length; _j < _len1; _j++) {
              item = data1[_j];
              _this.sections.push(new MyNamespace.MySection(item));
            }
            return alert("click Ok to make pie chart disappear =[");
          };
        })(this);
```

Comment: I guess the data which is coming from the server is not an array. Please check that the `data1` contains an array in your callback function!

Comment: @nemesv unfortunately it is an array. Weird thing is that my chart and that sections array aren't related - I have a table where I am using ko foreach: section (to display each section as a row). And another weird thing is that if I use simple line chart instead of pie chart everything works fine.

Comment: Can you duplicate your issue within [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/LK74R/)? I didn't setup the github resources for Chrome/IE compatibility, so Firefox it is.